# Does the number of rows using rest api in a webserver affect the bandwidth usage?

Tags: php, reactjs

I am using 000webhost (free tier) as an online database (MySQL) for my applications using PHP REST API and I am kinda worried that my apps would accumulate up to the bandwidth usage limit per month. Does the number of rows retrieved each time a request in API has been made affect the bandwidth usage? I have tried spamming requests to the API and it seems that there's an only little amount that was added to the bandwidth usage. Although I would like to have some tips from experts here.

Comment: What does `using PHP REST API` mean in regards to your database? Is your website and database on the same host `000webhost`? Can you explain more about your application stack?

Comment: Oh yeah, im using php to make an api that connects to the online database for my electron app. basically I just fetch the PHP API using nodejs fetch and it will return the data from the online database.

Comment: It depends on your API, for instance, if your API return a an identifiable resource, only the number of client will affect brandwidth. If your API return a list of documents, without paginating results, the number of line in database and the number of client will affect your brandwidth

Comment: What do you mean by identifiable resource? anyways tnx for the answer. i get it now.